# AWS DAX cluster has zero cache hits and cache miss

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I'm using an AWS DAX cluster of 3 nodes of dax.r4.xlarge node type. When I'm running my spark application from EMR cluster, it is always fetching values from dynamodb table. Even if I run the same application on same set of key, it is querying dynamodb table. In the DAX cluster metrics I see 0 cache hits and misses.

Comment: Are you querying the dax endpoint, or Dynamo?

Comment: Dax endpoint with client without a session

Comment: @hephalump Thanks for the help. I fixed it. Added the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the mistake. Initially I was hitting DynamoDB directly and was using consistent reads by defining get item input parameter as:
`ConsistentRead: aws.Bool(true)` 
When I switched to DAX client, I did not remove it. Hence it was always redirecting all the requests to Dynamodb table to keep the reads consistent.
Removing this worked. I can see cache hits and misses in DAX metrics now.